# Best practice for storing a singleton instance in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, static, global-asax

If we have a singleton class like `LoadBalancer` and need one instance per `ASP.NET` application, then where to store it ?

Currently I use `Application.Add("LoadBalancer", LoadBalancer.Instance)` in `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax`.

Also `Application` object is created by `ASP.NET` and there are multiple instances per application based on workload. Also I can declare a `static` instance of my `LoadBalancer` in `Global.asax`.

Which is preferred ? Any better idea ?

Comment: I'm with Cybernate here, this sounds like a seriously flawed design.  What, exactly, is the LoadBalancer object doing?  Because quite frankly if it is attempting to load balance traffic on your site then you've gone about this in a completely wrong way.

Comment: If you're trying to keep the "one object to rule them all" across multiple web servers in a farm, you're probably going to have to store it in a database and retrieve it every time you need it, utilizing the appropriate concurrency rules of course.

Comment: `LoadBalancer` here is not the known load balancer in server farms. It's a object of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a Singleton why do you want to store in Application items? Isn't it supposed to return the same instance when you use LoadBalancer.Instance from anywhere in the application?

In case your site is using load balancing or is ina web farm each server would have its instance of Application  object and LoadBalancer.Instance.

Comment: @Aliostad: Can you please let me know what am I missing or understood wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to store a singleton object in Application object. Standard implementation of Singleton object holds good. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

But if you using a Web Farm its a different story, you should have the Singleton object hosted seperately on a different service and all the servers should request the object from that service using Remoting or WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IOC container like Castle Windsor. The default lifestyle in Castle Windsor is singleton.

http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/lifestyles.html